# Why can't I get my CPU fan speed info or data or anything other than temperature?

Tags: c#, openhardwaremonitor

I'm using OpenHardwareMonitorLib.dll in my project. I have this function in a class:

```
public static void cpuView(bool pause , CpuTemperature cpuTemp , Form1 f1 , List<string> myData , float? myCpuTemp , Button b1)
        {
            if (pause == true)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                Computer myComputer = new Computer();
                myComputer = new Computer(cpuTemp)
                {
                    CPUEnabled =

                        true
                };

                myComputer.Open();
                Trace.WriteLine("");
                foreach (var hardwareItem in myComputer.Hardware)
                {
                    if (hardwareItem.HardwareType == HardwareType.CPU)
                    {
                        hardwareItem.Update();
                        foreach (IHardware subHardware in hardwareItem.SubHardware)
                            subHardware.Update();

                        foreach (var sensor in hardwareItem.Sensors)
                        {
                            cpuTemp.SetValue("sensor", sensor.Value.ToString());
                            if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
                            {
                                sensor.Hardware.Update();
                                cpuTemp.GetValue("sensor", sensor.Value.ToString());                                
                                f1.Invoke(new Action(() => myData.Add("Cpu Temeprature --- " + sensor.Value.ToString())));
                                myCpuTemp = sensor.Value;
                                if (sensor.Value > 60)
                                {


                                    Logger.Write("The Current CPU Temperature Is ===> " + sensor.Value);
                                    b1.Enabled = true;
                                }

                                break;
                            }
                            if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Fan)
                            {
                                sensor.Hardware.Update();
                                cpuTemp.GetValue("sensor", sensor.Value.ToString());
                                f1.Invoke(new Action(() => myData.Add("Cpu Temeprature --- " + sensor.Value.ToString())));
                                myCpuTemp = sensor.Value;
                                if (sensor.Value > 60)
                                {
                                    Logger.Write("The Current CPU Temperature Is ===> " + sensor.Value);
                                    b1.Enabled = true;
                                }
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

This function is working. I can get and see the CPU temperature.
But once I change the sensor type to anything else like Fan on this line:

```
if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Temperature)
```

To

```
if (sensor.SensorType == SensorType.Fan)
```

Then it will be == equal only if `SensorType` is `Temperature`.
How can I get other info of other hardware of my CPU other then temperature ?

cpuTemp is another class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using OpenHardwareMonitor.Hardware;

namespace HardwareMonitoring
{
    class CpuTemperature:ISettings
    {    
        public CpuTemperature()
        {

        }

        private IDictionary<string, string> settings = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        public CpuTemperature(IDictionary<string, string> settings)
        {
            this.settings = settings;

        }

        public bool Contains(string name)
        {
            return settings.ContainsKey(name);
        }

        public string GetValue(string name, string value)
        {
            string result;
            if (settings.TryGetValue(name, out result))
                return result;
            else
                return value;
        }

        public void Remove(string name)
        {
            settings.Remove(name);
        }

        public void SetValue(string name, string value)
        {
            settings[name] = value;
        }

    }
}
```

I forgot to mention that in Form1 in the constructor I have this:

```
cpu = new CpuTemperature(new Dictionary<string, string>
            {
                { "/intelcpu/0/temperature/0/values", "H4sIAAAAAAAEAOy9B2AcSZYlJi9tynt/SvVK1+B0oQiAYBMk2JBAEOzBiM3mkuwdaUcjKasqgcplVmVdZhZAzO2dvPfee++999577733ujudTif33/8/XGZkAWz2zkrayZ4hgKrIHz9+fB8/Iu6//MH37x79i9/+NX6N3/TJm9/5f/01fw1+fosnv+A/+OlfS37/jZ/s/Lpv9fff6Ml/NTef/yZPnozc5679b+i193//TQZ+/w2Dd+P9/sZeX/67v/GTf/b3iP3u4/ObBL//73+i+f039+D8Zk/+xz/e/P6beu2TQZju8yH8f6OgzcvPv/U3/Rb8+z/0f/9b/+yfaOn8079X6fr6Cws7ln/iHzNwflPv99/wyS/+xY4+v/evcJ+733+jJ5//Cw7/4ndy9Im3+U2e/Fbnrk31C93vrt/fyPvdb+N//hsF7/4/AQAA//9NLZZ8WAIAAA==" },
                { "/intelcpu/0/load/0/values", "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" },
            });
```

Comment: Is this a laptop or desktop? If desktop, please specify the make and model of the motherboard.

Comment: Desktop the model is gigabyte EX58-UD3R i can get the cpu temperature but can't get any other info like Fan speed. Maybe it's something eith the settings in the CpuTemperature class the settings i enter in Form1 constructor as i show above.